# Jetpack Compose Button Not Updating Despite Implementation with mutableStateOf

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I am relatively new to Jetpack Compose, and I'm facing an issue with a simple button click not updating the number as expected. I have a Counter composable that takes an initial count value and a lambda for updating the count. However, despite using `mutableStateOf` and passing the correct click handler, the count doesn't seem to increase when the button is clicked.

Here is my `MainActivity` code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            DemoTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val post by remember {
                        mutableStateOf(Post())
                    }
                    Counter(post.likes) {
                        post.likes = it + 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the `Counter` composable:

```
@Composable
fun Counter(postLikes: Int, onLikeClick: (Int) -> Unit) {
    val count = remember { mutableStateOf(postLikes) }
    Column(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                onLikeClick(count.value)
            }
        ) {
            Text("Click me")
        }
        Text(text = "Current count: ${count.value}")
    }
}
```

The `Post` model:

```
class Post(){
    var title: String = ""
    var content: String = ""
    var likes = 0
}
```

This seems simple enough to be working, but still, the count remains the same after clicking the button. Can someone please point out what might be going wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

I attempted to implement a simple counter using Jetpack Compose, where a button click should increase the count. Here are the key steps I took:

Created a Counter composable that accepts the initial count value and a lambda for count updates.
Used the mutableStateOf to handle the state of the count variable.
Integrated this Counter composable within the MainActivity, passing the initial count from a Post instance.
I expected that clicking the button would trigger the lambda to update the count, and the displayed count in the UI would increase accordingly.

What actually resulted?

Despite implementing the above steps, clicking the button did not result in an increase in the displayed count. The count remained the same, suggesting that the state update might not be happening as intended.

Any insights or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compose is not able to track changes to internal state of an object saved in `MutableState`. You need to update state's value, i.e. assign it a new instance of `Post`. To facilitate that, you can convert `Post` into a `data class` and use its `copy` function.

Another thing - you don't need to use `remember` on `postLikes`. It is an external value, `Counter` doesn't change it.

Post

```
data class Post(
    var title: String = "",
    var content: String = "",
    var likes: Int = 0
)
```

Counter

```
@Composable
fun Counter(postLikes: Int, onLikeClick: (Int) -> Unit) {
    Column(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                onLikeClick(postLikes)
            }
        ) {
            Text("Click me")
        }
        Text(text = "Current count: $postLikes")
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var post by remember {
    mutableStateOf(Post())
}
Counter(post.likes) {
    post = post.copy(likes = it + 1)
}
```

Moreover, you can simplify your composable a bit by not passing `postLikes` in `onLikeClick` from `Counter` to its caller.

```
@Composable
fun Counter(postLikes: Int, onLikeClick: () -> Unit) {
    Column(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = onLikeClick
        ) {
            Text("Click me")
        }
        Text(text = "Current count: $postLikes")
    }
}
```

```
Counter(post.likes) {
    val current = post.likes
    post = post.copy(likes = current + 1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It works as expected. However, is there a more Compose-friendly way to handle this without directly reassigning the post variable? In Jetpack Compose, shouldn't UI updates happen automatically when the state changes? Any insights on a cleaner approach are appreciated.

Comment: You could make properties of `Post` to be mutable states instead of `Post` itself. But In a real app most of the time you wouldn't have to do this. Your `onLikeClick` would trigger data update in some repository and you would get a whole new `Post` state back, so it won't look so ugly. @AhmedEl-Hady

Answer (score 0):

`postLikes` in `Counter` does not need to be wrapped in remember, as it will be recomposed only when `postLikes` value updates. Just use `postLikes` in `Counter` Composable